# Changing div class within set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html and I want to change the divs around onclick.  For example:

Initial

```
<div class="box1">Story 1</div>
<div class="box2">Story 2</div>
<div class="box2">Story 3</div> 
<div class="box2">Story 4</div>
```

When I click on Story 2, it becomes

```
<div class="box2">Story 1</div>
<div class="box1">Story 2</div>
<div class="box2">Story 3</div> 
<div class="box2">Story 4</div>
```

So .. whichever div is clicked will take the property of box1 and the others will become box2.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
$('.box1, .box2').click(function() {
    $('.box1').addClass('box2').removeClass('box1');
    $(this).addClass('box1').removeClass('box2');
});
```

It might be neater to have one `box` class for all boxes, and one `active` class that you add and remove, and the latter class could override the properties of the former. Would save you the trouble of toggling two different classes.

Answer (score 4):

One more possible solution with [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method:

```
$("div").on("click", function() {
    $(this)
        .siblings(".box1")
        .andSelf()
        .toggleClass("box1 box2");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/x8vxh/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("div").on("click",function(){
  $(".box1").prop("class","box2");
  $(this).prop("class","box1");
});
```

http://jsbin.com/igugop/3/edit